# How is this sentence formed: "The seniors make the freshers write practical files."

Tags: syntactic-analysis, bare-infinitive, grammatical-roles, causative-verbs

How is this sentence constructed?

> The seniors make the freshers write practical files.

Comment: Is *freshers* supposed to be *freshmen*? That aside, please be more specific. It has the normal subject-verb-object structure.

Comment: @JasonBassford Usually called *freshers* in Britain. Do you have female *freshmen*?

Comment: @WS2 The is the first time I've ever heard *freshers*. But, yes, unless there is an explicit attempt to use gender-neutral language, *freshmen* refers to all such students. I simply use *first-year students*. Or *I'm in my first year*.

Comment: @Jason freshers mean junior first year student

Comment: I am not clear about use of make here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we use zero infinitives with make, let, have?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/443192/why-do-we-use-zero-infinitives-with-make-let-have) (I made you do [something].)

Comment: [The seniors] [make [the freshers] [write [practical files]]]. Just like [your parents] [make [you] [do [your homework]]].

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perhaps it is the sense of *make*, meaning *force* that is troubling the OP here. If you "make" someone do something, it implies you have absolute power over them - it is often used with children. "His mother made him apologise to the person he had called a stupid old geezer". I'm sure you know that but perhaps the questioner doesn't.

Comment: @WS2 'Formed' and 'constructed' strongly suggests syntax to my mind. (The notional agreement intended.)

Comment: "To make someone do something" is a very common turn of phrase, in English as well as other languages, because it's a very common human activity universally observed on a daily basis by all people worldwide. It should be included in every dictionary, but even if it weren't, the meaning of the whole is directly derived from the meaning of the individual parts and as such is self-explanatory.

Comment: @RegDwight thanks a lot .Now use of make in above sentence is very much cleared to me 

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes. I don't know where the OP is from. There is another question out there at the moment about "make". It seems to confuse people who are not of a Romance inheritance. Our various uses clearly derive from the Latin *facere* - *faire* in French.

Comment: @WS2 I am a romantic person though

Comment: @WS2 Bengali language which is the sweetest language in world

Comment: @WS2 though it's a personal question but I am very curious about to know your personal life .are you a faculty for this website ? If you are  not then what is the purpose for answering so many questions ?I mean we have many works to do everyday .