# Girls who I've made [to] love me

Tags: infinitives, bare-infinitive, causative-verbs

Is that "to" mandatory and needed, or is it wrong and unneeded?

> I give my friend great advice, saying to them how they shouldn't treat girls by telling my story, "All the girls who I've made [to] love me forcefully, have eventually dumped me away."

Comment: The first question in the duplicate list contains [an answer by Prof. Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/443216/2085) and the second [one of his comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144573/why-do-these-verbs-take-bare-infinitives#comment297351_144573) that both explain the practice and origin of verbs that take bare infinitives like *make, let, have* as part of the “grammaticalization cycle”. Sense verbs like *see, watch, hear* also do this trick of skipping the *to* the way modal verbs always do, but less lexicalized verbs like *want, allow, direct, require* do not.

Comment: Plastic dummies I've made to love me. Think about that for a moment.

Comment: But I still don't understand if that "to" is needed.